# How to install "geopip2" module in nginx container ( nginx/1.17.8)?

Tags: docker, nginx

I want to install `geoip2` module on nginx. While looking on the [document](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/modules/geoip2/), it's supported for Nginx Plus.

Little confused, can we install `geopip2` module on Nginx container?

Below is existing version and modules enabled

```
nginx version: nginx/1.17.8
built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.17.8/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.17.8=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are my findings:
`Geoip2` is dynamic module and doesn't falls under Nginx OSS version.
We have to install Nginx Plus to have `Geoip2` module enabled.

Answer (score 0):

> We have to install Nginx Plus to have Geoip2 module enabled.

That's not true.

You can get Nginx to load GeoIP2 module, see this post:
https://admintuts.net/server-admin/docker/custom-nginx-docker-image-geoip2-rtmp-support/

I do like this:

```bash
docker run \
        --name=nginx \
        --user=nginx \
        --env=NGINX_GUI=2000 \
        --volume=/somedir/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html \
        --volume=/somedir/nginx/etc:/etc/nginx \
        -p 443:3443 \
        -p 80:3080 \        
        --restart=unless-stopped \
        --detach=true \
        admintuts/nginx:1.21.4-rtmp-geoip2-alpine
```